# HTTP GET Requests with HTTP-Basic from Flash Player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, http, basic-authentication

Unfortunately, Flash Player doesn't support using request headers with `GET` requests, as noted [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#requestHeaders), due to what Adobe terms "browser limitations":

> Due to browser limitations, custom HTTP request headers are only supported for `POST` requests, not for `GET` requests.

Hooray. That means I need to create my own HTTP socket class from scratch and find a way to run a policy server on the machine I'll be querying. Hooray.

If I want to make a simple GET HTTP request with HTTP-Basic auth headers, what do I need? I'd need something like

```
socket.write("HTTP GET REQUEST PAYLOAD HERE");
socket.flush();
```

What do I put in the write method to compose a GET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much more worth it to simply write a PHP or Python proxy to do it for you. See [file_get_contents: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960722/file-get-contents-connection-refused).