# file_get_contents: Connection refused

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have the following code which runs fine on my computer but fails online:

```
<?PHP
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");

    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $url = "http://s6.voscast.com:7158/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml";

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array (
            'method' => "GET",
            'header' => "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($username.":".$password)."\r\n".
                        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/14.0.835.202 Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
        )
    ));

    print file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
?>
```

This totally works locally; I'm able to GET the URL behind HTTP-Basic authentication and print it.

However, when I upload it to my server, it doesn't work and spits this out:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(http://s6.voscast.com:7158/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in <b>/home/livshin/public_html/wp-content/uploads/_radio/songinfo.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
```

Is there a way I can get a stack trace on this or something which will at least give me better information on what went wrong?

* I've already tested to make sure that something like `file_get_contents("http://google.com/")` works on the server.

Comment: Your server probably doesn't allow outgoing connections on port 7158. Google, being on port 80, works correctly. Can you change the firewall?

Comment: Best thing to "stack trace" this is using a network monitor on your server and watch what happens with the connection to that server. For a try you can set the headers as an array (not as a string with `"\r\n"`). Depending on the `http://` streamwrapper registered internally this could make a difference. But no guarantee that this works. Do you have SSH access to the server (shell)? Maybe with `curl -v` on the commandline you'll get more info, especially with that part as minitech commented.

Comment: @minitech That definitely sounds like the problem. Just asked for SSH access.

Comment: @minitech Please create an answer with your comment above, and I'll award you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server probably doesn't allow outgoing connections on port 7158. Google, being on port 80, works correctly. You might need to change the firewall.